# Sliding down inputs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been trying to make an input slide down using `.slideDown()` but it doesn't seem to be working, unless I'm just putting in in the wrong place.

I'm basically wanting the `input_line` to slide down when you click 'Add Field' instead of just appearing instantly for a nicer effect.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="add">Add Field</button>
    <div class='input_line'>
        <input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input1">
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
   var input = 1,
        blank_line = $('.input_line');

    $('#add').click(function () {
        $('form').append(blank_line.clone(true));
        $('.input_line').last().before().before($(this));
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emL6gx18/)**

I have tried this:
`$('form').append(blank_line.clone(true).slideDown());`

Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to hide the element before showing it with `slideDown()`. `slideDown` is essentially an animated `show` function. They behave the same: calling `show` on an already visible element does nothing.

Additionally the button can be animated by keeping it where it is and changing it to be absolutely positioned.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var input = 1,
        blank_line = $('.input_line');
    
    $('#add').click(function () {
        var newElement = blank_line.clone(true).hide();
        $('form').append(newElement);
        newElement.slideDown();
    });
});
```

```css
#add {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.input_line {
    margin-left: 70px;
}
form {
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="add">Add Field</button>
    <div class='input_line'>
        <input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input1">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why did you need to add a new variable?

Comment: @Jordan, don't I need to call `slideDown()` after the element has been appended? A variable makes it more readable than re-finding the element.

Comment: Yes I guess it does make it more readable and a little cleaner in some aspects. So you should always hide an element before using the `.slideDown()` function?

Comment: Yes, `slideDown` is essentially an animated `show` function. They behave the same: calling `show` on an already visible element does nothing.

Comment: Oh ok, I'll have a read up on the jQuery documentation about that, that's for the help! :)

Comment: Ok, I have just created a new fiddle with an extra feature, how could I apply  the same effect? http://jsfiddle.net/fbcut00p/

Comment: Do the same thing as with the other button. hide the new element, add it to the document (the before function does that), show it with `slideDown`.

Comment: Would you mind updating the fiddle so I can see a working version? I'm new to using jQuery animations so I'm trying to grasp this, sorry.

Comment: While the code in your external resource might well be correct, it should be here included in your answer. Demonstrations are very nice, and useful, but they're to be used *in addition to* a fully fleshed-out and explained answer. They're not a substitute.

Comment: @DavidThomas I don't know what you're trying to explain by that?

Comment: It was intended for the author of this answer, not you; however I was meaning quite simply: that the answer should contain the code that supposedly answers the question.