# Do you need to always hide the element when using jQuery slideDown function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I asked a question regarding something related to this earlier but the guy who answered didn't really explain his answer that great.

When you click the 'duplicate' button on my form, I would like the input field to slide down instead of just appearing.

He said you always have to hide the element using the `hide()` function before using the `slideDown()` function, is this correct?

**HTML:**

```
 <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <button id="add">Add Field</button>
    <div class='input_line'>
        <input type="text" name="input_0" placeholder="Input1"><input type="button" class="duplicate" value="duplicate">
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var input = 1,
        blank_line = $('.input_line');

    $('#add').click(function () {
        var newElement = blank_line.clone(true).hide();
        $('form').append(newElement);
        $(newElement).slideDown();
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function () {
        $(this).parent().after($(this).parent().clone());
        $('.input_line').last().before($('#add'));
        input = input + 1;
    });
});
```

Fiddle updated. **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fbcut00p/)**

What's the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Can include link to _"question regarding something related to this earlier"_ ?

Comment: @guest271314 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280850/sliding-down-inputs-with-jquery

Comment: @guest271314 I had a look at the jQuery Documentation but I'm still a little confused on how to implement that into what I'm trying to do, this is the first time I've eve really messed around with jQuery animation, any advice?

Comment: _"but the guy who answered didn't really explain his answer that great."_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280850/sliding-down-inputs-with-jquery#comment48660271_30280880 ? Is `js` at http://jsfiddle.net/emL6gx18/2/ not returning expected results ?

Comment: Yeah that scenario is working great, and I understand how he did that. I'm just confused how I would apply the same effect the duplicate function?

Comment: What is expected result of `.before($('#add'));` ? Is requirement to display `.slideDown()` effect at each `.input_line` clone appended to document ?

Comment: $('.input_line').last().before($('#add')).hide().slideDown();  -- http://jsfiddle.net/vjpm9v2r/

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou so it is necessary to always `hide()` before using the `slideDown()` function?

Comment: yes or use css class for the input (display:none;) although you will need to overnight the ist one with (style="display:block;") directly on the input to show. however you seem to clone so it will clone the style too so use the (hide())

Comment: So if I use the `display: none` declaration I could leave out the `hide()` function?

Comment: No because you are cloning. If you want to use the (display:none) you will need to use (append("....") the input

Comment: I think I will just stick with using the `hide()` function, I was wanting to see what other option there were. I'm still a little confused on where you put that in the code. I would have thought it should have gone like this `$(this).parent().after($(this).parent().clone().hide().slideDown());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.insertAfter()`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var input = 1,
        blank_line = $('.input_line');

    $('#add').click(function () {
        var newElement = blank_line.clone(true).hide();
        $('form').append(newElement);
        $(newElement).slideDown();
    });

    $('form').on('click', '.duplicate', function () {
        $(this).parent().clone().hide().insertAfter($(this).parent().after()).slideDown();
        $('.input_line').last().before($('#add'));
        input = input + 1;
    });
});
```

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fbcut00p/5/

Hope it can help.

Comment: I just edit this line cause you said you want slide down animation instead of just appearing.
$(this).parent().clone().hide().insertAfter($(this).parent().after()).slideDown();

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier doing this though: `$('.input_line').last().before($('.add')).hide().slideDown();`?

Comment: Yeah.But I guess with that, the animation will apply to the last element, not to the element just added(duplicated).

Comment: Oh, yeah I see what you mean now, your method actually looks a lot nicer now I take a closer look at it. I've also added a remove button and I tried using `.slideUp().remove();` if I use just `slideUp()` it works fine but it leaves the div in there hence why I tried using `remove()`, how can I also remove it? Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gqgaswdy/

Comment: @Jordan _"I've also added a remove button and I tried using .slideUp().remove();"_ , _"how can I also remove it?"_ ? This does appear at original Question ? Original question appear to have two parts 1) _"have to hide the element using the hide() function before using the slideDown() function, is this correct?"_ ; 2) _"What's the easiest way of doing this?"_ . Perhaps ask separate Question(s) , instead of adding on to original Question at comments ? Have the two parts of initial Question been resolved ?

Comment: @guest271314 There isn't much point making a new question when it's related to my original question. I feel RRayasa has had the best response so far so I'm asking for further advice.

Comment: @Jordan See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: @guest271314 Like I said in my previous comment, I'm asking for further advice that's related with my original question. I'm not looking for any negativity.

Answer (score 0):

> have to hide the element using the hide() function before using the
>   slideDown() function, is this correct?

see `jQuery` version`1.11.3` source at lines ***7614-7626*** ; `$.fn.slideDown()` , `$.fn.slideUp()` appear to be alias of `.show()` , `.hide()` , respectively

```
// Generate shortcuts for custom animations
jQuery.each({
    slideDown: genFx("show"), // <-
    slideUp: genFx("hide"), // <-
    slideToggle: genFx("toggle"),
    fadeIn: { opacity: "show" },
    fadeOut: { opacity: "hide" },
    fadeToggle: { opacity: "toggle" }
}, function( name, props ) {
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( speed, easing, callback ) {
        return this.animate( props, speed, easing, callback );
    };
});
```

Comment: I have updated the fiddle. I tested your fiddle and the effect works but it doesn't actually duplicate anything once you type into the input.

Comment: @Jordan _"it doesn't actually duplicate anything once you type into the input. "_ ? Input "abc" , clicked "duplicate" , cloned element appear to slide down , here ? Can describe _"it doesn't actually duplicate anything"_ ? element , or input text ?  See with `#add` http://jsfiddle.net/fbcut00p/1/

Comment: Yes I have, adding a new field works perfect but I'm still no further forward with adding this same effect to the 'duplicate' button?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/fbcut00p/2/. Same effect applied to `Add`, `duplicate` buttons. Effect not appear , there ?

Comment: No the effect is only applying to the last button, and not all of them.

Comment: Oh it's because of `last()` before `slideDown()`, can you please update your answer instead of the comments.

Comment: That's still not the correct answer, you need to keep the `last()` function or it just keeps adding buttons every time you duplicate.

Comment: What is purpose of  _"Oh it's because of last() before slideDown()"_ ? ; keep `.last()` within `js` ? See also updated post as to this portion of original Question _"have to hide the element using the hide() function before using the slideDown() function, is this correct?"_

Comment: Ok, let's start from scratch. Read my question again.

Comment: I have and with the code in your fiddle when you press 'duplicate' it keep adding an new 'Add Field' button. They get altered on top of each other if you inspect the element.

Comment: Is requirement for there to be only one "Add Field" button within the document ? If yes, could remove `.before($("#add"))` ? http://jsfiddle.net/fbcut00p/4/

Comment: Yes, only one. They way the code I proved in my question should stay the same way apart from I want it so when you press 'duplicate' it will slide down instead of just appearing, I provided all of this information in my original answer. This should be a simple answer.